# Spring: Adding one record to a List suddenly creates a duplicate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, session

To pick up Spring, I'm playing around with very simple pages to understand the annotations and the behaviors of Spring in general. To be precise, I created a page to show a list of `Task` and another page to add a new `Task`. I used `@SessionAttibutes` to save the list of Task in the session instead of calling a service to retrieve a full list of `Task` everytime I access the task list page.

This is my `TaskService`

```
@Service
public class TaskService {
  private List<Task> taskCache = new ArrayList<Task>();

  public List<Task> retrieveTasks() {
    System.out.println("GETTING TASK LIST FOR THE FIRST TIME");
    return taskCache;
  }

  public Task addTask(String title, String desc, Date targetDate) {
    Task newTask = new Task(title, desc, targetDate);
    taskCache.add(newTask);

    return newTask;
  }
}
```

This is my `TaskController`

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("taskList")
public class TaskController {
  @Autowired
  private TaskService taskService;

  @GetMapping("/task-view")
  public String showTaskList() {
    return "task/view";
  }

  @GetMapping("/task-add")
  public String showAddTaskForm(@ModelAttribute("task") Task newTask) {
    return "task/add";
  }

  @PostMapping("/task-add")
  public String addTask(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("task") Task newTask, @ModelAttribute("taskList") List<Task> taskList) {
    System.out.println("ADDING NEW TASK: " + taskList.size());
    taskList.add(taskService.addTask(newTask.getTitle(), newTask.getDesc(), new Date()));
    System.out.println("DONE ADDING NEW TASK: " + taskList.size());
    return "redirect:/task-view";
  }

  @ModelAttribute("taskList")
  public List<Task> taskList() {
    System.out.println("CALLING TASK SERVICE TO GET LIST OF TASKS");
    return taskService.retrieveTasks();
  }
}
```

This is my `view.jsp`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Task Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is your task list:
    ${taskList}

    <div>
      <a href="task-add">Add a task</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `add.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Task Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/task-add" modelAttribute="task">
      <div>
        <form:label path="title">Title</form:label>
        <form:input path="title" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <form:label path="desc">Description</form:label>
        <form:input path="desc" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
      </div>
    </form:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In term of the session-scoped attribute, it's working as I expect. The `TaskService.retrieveTasks()` function is only called the 1st time I access the `view.jsp`. Subsequently, the same list of task is pulled from the Session.

The problem is when I try to add two new `Task` on the `add.jsp` page, I saw the following lines in the console.

```
CALLING TASK SERVICE TO GET LIST OF TASKS
GETTING TASK LIST FOR THE FIRST TIME
ADDING NEW TASK: 0
DONE ADDING NEW TASK: 2
ADDING NEW TASK: 2
DONE ADDING NEW TASK: 4
```

The 1st two lines were printed when I accessed the `view.jsp` for the 1st time, which is right. However, I have no idea what's happening between the `ADDING NEW TASK` and `DONE ADDING NEW TASK` lines. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain to me why the line below is adding a duplicate in my list of `Task`

```
taskList.add(taskService.addTask(newTask.getTitle(), newTask.getDesc(), new Date()));
```

I also tried to remove the `taskList.add()` portion and only made a service call to `taskService.addTask()`. In this case, there's no duplicate and my `taskList` is updated with one new record. However, I don't understand how the `taskService` could indirectly modify my `taskList` when there's no injection in the `TaskService` class.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You reference the same list twice, and thus add the `Task` twice to the same list. The dangers of caching... Instead of trying to sync the cache just add it once in the service and just refresh the cached list. Instead of trying to manually keep them up-to-date...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I tried to implement a simple example to learn Spring. I thought I was misunderstanding Spring in some way and I never realized I made such a basic Java mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the method `retrieveTasks`:

```
public List<Task> retrieveTasks() {
    System.out.println("GETTING TASK LIST FOR THE FIRST TIME");
    return taskCache;
}
```

This method returns a reference to the `taskCache` object. Everybody with access to this reference can modify this mutable List. E.g. in PHP, if you returned an array, than by default, you would receive a copy of the array. Not in Java.

You should modify the method like this:

```
public List<Task> retrieveTasks() {
        System.out.println("GETTING TASK LIST FOR THE FIRST TIME");
        return new ArrayList<>(taskCache); // create copy of taskCache
}
```

This is in fact, what a real service would be doing. Data would be stored in a database, but you would not return a direct reference to that data. You would always pull current data from DB and materialize it in a brand new List.

Comment: Damn. Thank you. I spent way too much time thinking about Spring that I didn't realize such a basic mistake in Java!

Answer (score 2):

```
  @ModelAttribute("taskList")
  public List<Task> taskList() {
    System.out.println("CALLING TASK SERVICE TO GET LIST OF TASKS");
    return taskService.retrieveTasks();
  }
```

I think that's what you're missing. taskList() method returns taskCache list and that's the list taskService modifies. So taksList and taskCache are the same object.